# How SqLite figure out request which contain date format?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on an android project which retrieves information from a database and stores it (using SqLite for Java side).

Here is my request:

```
String Query = 

"SELECT xxx.APP_ID " + "FROM xxx INNER JOIN yyy ON
xxx.APP_ID = yyy.APP_ID " +

"WHERE date('"+mydate+"') BETWEEN date(xxx.APP_DATEBEGIN) AND date(xxx.APP_DATEEND)
" +

"AND (yyy.USR_ID = " + myid + ") " +

"ORDER BY xxx.APP_DATEBEGIN";
```

`mydate` format is : `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` which is the same format with the date in the database.

I execute the same request (Sql server side) with convert which works fine. I think that the keyword `date` is not available in SqLite.

Is there a another way to do this?

Comment: Yes, the keyword date() exists. You can see all the date and time functions here: (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)
This link is very useful for date issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, you do not need to use any function to represent date - just use plain string that contains date: [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb/4).

This is in agreement with [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

on section 1.2 you can see the options for dating format (I also suggest bookmarking this site as it's VERY useful)

Personally I like using UNIX UTC time system as it is easy to compare against other dates using >, < and = and it's kinda of a universal system, as it doesn't care for regionalisation.